# Problem with wind (Doppler Effect)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, doppler-effect

Mi physics book has a problem that states

> The C note has a frequency $\nu=261,6$Hz. In an open concert wind blows from the stage to the audience vith speed $v_o=6m/s$.What is thefrequency heard by the audience?

My solution is: if we put ourselves in a reference system in which the air is not moving, both the audience and the muscian are moving with the same velocity; the audience is going toward the musician and the musician is going away from the audience, by applying the law of Doppler effect the frquency is $$\nu'=\left( \dfrac{v+6}{v+6} \right)\nu$$ so it is the same, but it is not the answer the book gives. Why am I wrong?

Comment: Hint: the frequency emitted by the musicians is 261.6 Hz in their own reference frame, not in the reference frame of the wind.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.